# Find difference of amount between each date

Tags: sas

I have a set of data where I need to calculate the difference between each month but I am not sure where to start or how to do it. The as of dates will constantly change. At the end of this month March would be added and so on and so forth. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

First image is the data. Second is the output I need to achieve. 
[image: Beginning]

[image]

Comment: "calculate the difference between each month" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DIF()`

```
data want;
   set have;

    difference = dif(total_amount);
run;
```

See the [documentation here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n10t6w4op574ttn11yk68dottp7f.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) for further information.

Comment: Phenomenal Reeza. Thank you very much. I also appreciate the additional documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
data want;
  set have;

  retain prevmonth;

  difference = total_amount - prevmonth;

  output;

  prevmonth = total_amount;
run;
```

These kinds of data step exercises are good to practice alongside knowing useful wrappers like `dif`. `retain` and `output` are general and powerful tools in the SAS programmer's library.